Is purity convex in time?
Is the purity $\mathrm{Tr}[\rho(t)^2]$ of a quantum state $\rho(t)$ that evolves according to a time-independent Lindbladian $\partial_t \rho = \mathcal{L}[\rho]$ convex in time $t$?
I suspect the the answer is "no" in general, but I wonder whether there are any useful characterizations of the kinds of Lindbladians which lead to purities that are convex in time. The furthest I have gotten on my own is a sufficient condition which I suspect is not a necessary condition: if the map $\mathcal{L}^\dagger \mathcal{L} - \mathcal{L}\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ is positive ($\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ is the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}$), then the purity is convex in time. I arrived at this condition by expressing the second time derivative of purity as $\partial_t^2 \mathrm{Tr}[\rho(t)^2] = \mathrm{Tr}[\rho(t) ((\mathcal{L} + \mathcal{L}^\dagger)^2 + \mathcal{L}^\dagger \mathcal{L} - \mathcal{L} \mathcal{L}^\dagger)[\rho(t)]]$.
I'd also be interested in similar characterizations for any entanglement monotones of the form $\mathrm{Tr}[f(\rho(t))]$, where $f$ is a convex function.
Thanks!
Edit: this is a cross post from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4927440/are-there-any-useful-convexity-properties-of-quantum-dynamical-semigroups.

The following is only a partial answer: While your argument rightly shows that normal $\mathcal L$ (which means $e^{t\mathcal L}$ is unital) is sufficient for convex purity, numerics suggest this even holds for all time-independent Markovian unital processes.
Note that time independence is essential here: while unitality is equivalent to decreasing purity this is logically independent from convexity. In fact it is easy to write down an example of a time-dependent Markovian process with decreasing, but non-convex purity: consider the Lindbladian $\mathcal L(t)$ generated only by $V(t)=\sin(t)\sigma_x$. Because $V(t)$ is Hermitian $L(t)$ generates a unital process. Moreover, $\rho_0={\rm diag}(2/3,1/3)$ evolves like
$$
\rho(t)=e^{\int_0^tL(s)\,ds}\rho_0=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac12+\frac{1}{6} e^{\sin (t) \cos (t)-t} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6} e^{\sin (t) \cos (t)-t} \end{pmatrix}
$$
so the purity

—while of course decreasing—is not convex. The underlying mechanism here is that the factor $\sin(t)$ introduces varying speed of the evolution of $\rho_0$ towards the maximally mixed states which interferes with convexity. NB: the reason your proof does not work in the time-dependent realm anymore is that you get extra derivatives $\frac d{dt}L(t)$ which mess up the structure.

The other point of my post is to confirm your suspicion that there exist time-independent Markovian processes where the purity is not convex in $t$. Numerical search yielded the following counterexample: $\rho_0={\bf1}/2$ and our Lindbladian $\mathcal L$ is generated by one operator (in the usual way):
$$
V=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then the eigenvalues of $e^{tL}(\rho_0)$ evolve as

which leads to the following (non-convex!) purity

This behaviour also shows when looking at the trajectory of $\rho(t)$ in the Bloch ball:

(dynamics start in the middle and end up in the fixed point ((2/3,-1/3),(-1/3,1/3)). The reason for the oscillation in the purity is the little swirl the dynamics do in the end:


Thanks for the response! The counter example is interesting, though I suspect the dynamics in your example are not completely positive. Looking into unitality as a criterion is an interesting direction for sure...

Also, the observation that the Lindbladian being self-adjoint is a sufficient condition seems like a corollary of the observation in the OP that $\mathcal{L}^\dagger \mathcal{L} - \mathcal{L} \mathcal{L}^\dagger \geq 0$ is a sufficient condition.

@nlupugla 1. Not sure what you mean, I specified a Lindbladian in my counterexample (through 1 Lindblad-$V$) which is, of course, what characterizes CPTP dynamics. 2. That's fair and I must admit I don't know how I missed that in your question. But yes, your argument does indeed show the (strictly stronger) statement that $L$ being normal is enough; my bad! I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Neat that there are examples with such a behavior. Can this be understood as a combination of Hamiltonian evolution and damping towards a specific point on the Bloch sphere (I would imagine if the two are in-plane, the state would spiral around the equilibrium position)?

@NorbertSchuch Indeed, using standard methods (1, 2) it's easy to see that the $L$ induced by $V$ from my answer is equivalent to a Lindbladian with (traceless) Lindblad-V $|0\rangle\langle 1|$ & Hamiltonian $-\sigma_y/2$. So as dissipation drives the maximally mixed state to the ball's edge the Hamiltonian induces this spiraling; but only together do $H$ and $V$ leave ((2/3,-1/3),(-1/3,1/3)) invariant (i.e. this attractive fixed point is neither a fixed point of the $H$ nor the $V$ part individually)

@FrederikvomEnde Ah, thanks for the clarification regarding the Lindbladian. I misunderstood and thought your Lindbladian was just a left-multiplication by $V$.

Thanks for your detailed answer @FrederikvomEnde! I get the impression there is not a "textbook" answer to my question and I'd hate to ask you to do free research for me :). That said, I am interested in this problem and would be happy to look into it a bit more deeply together.
Regarding unitality, if the action of the dynamics is a convex combination of unitary dynamics, the overall dynamics should be convex as well. I'm not sure if that's equivalent to unitality or what constraints that imposes on the Linbdblad.

@nlupugla Out of curiosity, is there is a reason why you are interested in this question (except that it might just be interesting by itself) -- why is convexity of purity under dissipation interesting?

@NorbertSchuch In my particular case, I'm looking at times in an evolution that maximize entanglement. Photon loss specifically. I know that that one particular of time is a local optimum for all states, but it's tricky to show that it's also a global optimum. Showing convexity would be enough to be confident that my local is a global.

@nlupugla Ah, ok: So you care about a case where it is not monotonous, yet convex. Sounds even more tricky, I would think. Maybe it makes more sense if you ask a new question with your specific model, rather than asking a very general question (not that this is bad, on the contrary: but given Frederik's answer it seems likely there isn't a simple answer).

@NorbertSchuch Well, the particular case I'm interested in (relating to photon loss) is the research problem I'm tackling and I was hoping there might be some general results/characterizations I could use that people here might know. It seems like the general question unknown a possibly quite rich :)
